# how can i display round dot for active status in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In older code of react it just display the text active or in active for an user. Now I want to replace it to red or green small dot how can I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS

```
div .colored-circle {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 5px;
      margin-right: 5px;
      margin-bottom: -2px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 0.5px;
      border-color: black;
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
    }
```

Component:

```
const ColoredCircle = ({ color }) => {

  const styles = { backgroundColor: color };

  return color ? (
    <Fragment>
      <span className="colored-circle" style={styles} />
    </Fragment>
  ) : null;
};

export default ColoredCircle;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same logic you used to show 'active' or 'inactive' and instead of text add a div with css or img of the desired color.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use material UI, you can do like this:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const RADIUS_DOT = 1.5;
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  circle: {
    borderRadius: RADIUS_DOT,
    height: RADIUS_DOT * 2,
    width: RADIUS_DOT * 2,
    padding: 0,
  },
}));

const ColoredCircle = ({ color }) => {
  const styles = { backgroundColor: color };
  const classes = useStyles();

  return color ? (
    <Fragment>
      <span className={classes.circle} style={styles} />
    </Fragment>
  ) : null;
};

export default ColoredCircle;
```

Answer (score -1):

[you can use this package, can be helpful](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@uiw/react-color-circle)

**npm i react-color-circle**

```
import Circle from '@uiw/react-color-circle';

return (
<Circle
  colors={[ '#F44E3B' ]}
/>);
```